# Cannot install .NET 3.5 on SharePoint server and may need to remove/reinstall previous versions. Will I be okay?

Tags: sharepoint, .net, windows-update

My environment is Win server 2003 acting as an app server for a farm.

I need to install .NET 3.5 so that various applications may run on the SharePoint sites. Unfortunately this is not proving to be possible and the only course of action I see resolving it is to remove/reinstall all of .NET.

**My question is whether or not this will 'hurt' my SharePoint installation in any way. I need it to be a quick and painless process so that the server may come back up with minimal downtime.**

For anyone that's curious there is no error message left by the installer GUI or EventViewer -- however there is this left by VSSWMSIFailInfo.txt:

```
DDSet_Error: CConfigEntry::RefreshConfigFile could not load _spConfigDoc path=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\WSF30.tmp isSuccessful=0 Error code: 0x1
DDSet_Error: CFxInstaller::SetupExtensions extensionElement.Initialize failed.  cswMachineConfigPath=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\WSF30.tmp. Error code: 0x80004005
DDSet_Error: CFxInstaller::SetupBaseComponents SetupExtensions failed. Error code: 0x80004005
DDSet_Error: Setup failed. Error code: 0x80004005
```

The only relevant information I could find on this is this post on msdn: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/7bc9797b-10ec-42c5-a21e-99c2b45b83ad/. Unfortunately the suggested resolution did not work for me. Hence I am left with going for the shotgun solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the short answer: it will ruin your day.

Admittedly I removed .net using the removal tool and not through the control panel. SharePoint does not like to have .NET pulled out from under it.

**Here is how I fixed it without reinstalling SharePoint or IIS:**
(this takes place AFTER .NET has been removed and SharePoint is in agony)

1. downloaded/installed .NET 3.5 from microsoft which installs previous versions alongside
2. installed .NET updates from windows update (reboot)
3. installed more .NET updates/service packs from windows update (reboot)
4. fix machine.config (%WINDIR%\microsoft.net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\machine.config)
   In my case there was invalid markup in the `<processModel>` node (invalid quotes). I would suggest having this backed up just so you can overwrite the entire file -- I used procmon to figure out what file was being read when psconfigui.exe barfed. This may or may not be a problem you encounter as it seems fairly random.
5. Run SharePoint configuration wizard
6. add ASP.NET_2.0.50727 ISAPI filter to "Web Sites" in IIS Manager
7. Add wildcard application map for EACH SHAREPOINT SITE in IIS (site properties, home directory, configuration) to have C:\WINDOWS\microsoft.net\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll and "uncheck verify that file exists"
8. Ensure that ASP.NET & Windows SharePoint services are Allowed in the Web Services Extension section in IIS Manager

After all these steps (and probably an iisreset) SharePoint should finally be working again! What a nightmare

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will pitch a fit, and things will go down hill from there.

BACKUP your site(s) before you touch anything else, and then look at the ability to re-install the .NET Frameworks since they're the backbone of SP.